# How to remove jquery migrate on selected posts

Tags: jquery

There are working solutions to remove jquery-migrate ([popular solution](https://www.infophilic.com/remove-jquery-migrate-wordpress/)), however NONE for selected posts.

The problem is that they all rely on `wp_default_scripts` hook, where post id is not defined yet.

Question: How can I remove jquery-migrate for all posts BUT keep it on home page/front page?

Comment: Completely deregistering the script as suggested in the linked article seems inadvisable - if you install any extension which depends on migrate, it will break, and just having it registered will not lead to it being loaded on the frontend unless something explicitly enqueues it, or enqueues something else with it as a dependency. It would be better to update or replace whichever hook is enqueuing it instead. That said, to get the best possible answer, we'll need to know what is responsible for/dependent on migrate being enqueued!

Comment: @bosco Thanks. You are correct, I have to replace a plugin - but this will take some time... Until then, I want the rest of the site to perform faster.

Comment: Even without replacing the plugin, you can modify the script enquement - i.e. set a hook on the same action as the plugin uses to enqueue the script which depends on migrate, dequeue that script, then enqueue it again conditionally for the front page only. Or detaching that hook completely and use your own. It's not possible to suggest which route you should take without seeing what the plugin is doing to load migrate.

Comment: @bosco I shall try remove at ```wp_default_scripts``` hook, and add it later once the ```post id``` is defined. I am not sure which hook will work best. In general, i will not use plugins that rely on jquery migrate.